# State True or False

Tags: real-analysis, functions

There exists a continuous function **f:[0,1]** onto **[0,10]**, but there exists no continuous function **g:[0,1]** onto **(0,10)** . 
The answer is True. How??

Comment: The image of a compact set under a continuous map is compact.

Comment: "Functions" is (in my view) a silly tag. Half the questions on m.se involve functions.

Comment: An example *of what*?

Comment: Hardik, I'm *certain* you can find an example of a continuous function from $[0,1]$ onto $[0,10]$.

Comment: ok.... i'll try to find such an example. Thanks.

Comment: To build on @DanielFischer's answer — see http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Image_of_Compact_Space_is_Compact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the extreme value theorem, a continuous function $f$ from the closed interval $[0,1]$ onto (or even into) $(0,10)$ takes on a maximum $M$ and a minimum $m$ somewhere in $(0,10)$. But then any real in the interval $(0,m)$ is not taken on by $f$, so that $f$ is not onto. [Also $f$ cannot hit any real in $(M,10).$]

The extreme value theorem may be known by any calc 1 student, who might not know what "compactness" is.

Comment: Thanks ..... The idea just didnt come upon my mind.

Comment: @Hardik Yes, I thought for a moment one could start off with $f(0)$ somewhere in $(0,10)$, then "wiggle it around a lot" so as to pick up all of $(0,10)$. But then I recalled the max/min guaranteed by extreme value theorem.

Answer (score 1):

For a function to be continuous the pre-image of an open set should be open. Here the pre-image of the open set $(0,10)$ is closed $[0,1]$. Hence the function is not continuous

Comment: $[0,1]$ is open in the domain of the function (which is $[0,1]$). That argument doesn't settle it.

Comment: @Hardik In fact, it's one of definitions of a continuous function. To prove equivalence, you need to give us your definition of continuity.